# PayPal PDT SSL connection hangs up on my addon domain

Tags: ssl, paypal, connection, paypal-pdt

On my PayPal `autoReturn` page with a known-to-work **PHP** script to accommodate Payment Data Transfer, no matter what I do I keep getting this error message: `"Warning: fgets(): SSL: Connection reset by peer...*(on the line where this is: '$line = fgets($fp, 1024);'* "`

Before I ask my question, let me just say that I've tried everything suggested here and in any other forum or article that I've been advised to read, e.g. changing `HTTP 1.0` to `HTTP 1.1`, using `$res=stream_get_contents($fp, 1024)` instead of the `while loop` with `$line = fgets($fp, 1024)`, etc., etc. My problem persists.

Here's what I think might be the problem (and I'm hoping someone can tell me if I'm on the right track): My auto return page for PDT is on an add-on site and I'm thinking that PayPal hangs up when the shared SSL (for my primary domain on a shared server) isn't recognized. So I've asked my web host for SSL to be installed specifically for my add-on domain.

Could the add-on domain SSL thing be the reason for my warning message? Again, that message is: `"Warning: fgets(): SSL: Connection reset by peer...*(on the line where this is: '$line = fgets($fp, 1024);'* "`

Here's my code:

```
 //look if the parameter 'tx' is set in the GET request and that it  does not have a null or empty value
if(isset($_GET['tx']) && ($_GET['tx'])!=null && ($_GET['tx'])!= "") {
    $tx = $_GET['tx'];

    verifyWithPayPal($tx);
}
else {
    exitCode();
}

function verifyWithPayPal($tx) {
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';
    $tx_token = $tx;
    $auth_token = "MY SANDBOX AUTH_TOKEN HERE";
    $req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // url for paypal sandbox
    //$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno,   $errstr, 30);    

    // url for payal
    // $fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    // If possible, securely post back to paypal using HTTPS
    // Your PHP server will need to be SSL enabled.

     $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
        exitCode();
    } else {
        fputs($fp, $header . $req);        
        // read the body data
        $res = '';
        $headerdone = false;

         while (!feof($fp)) {
            $line = fgets($fp, 1024);
        // $res=stream_get_contents($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp($line, "\r\n") == 0) {
                // read the header
                $headerdone = true;
            }
            else if ($headerdone) {
                // header has been read. now read the contents
                $res .= $line;
            }
         }

        // parse the data
        $lines = explode("\n", $res);

        $response = array();

        if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {

            for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++){
                list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
                $response[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
            }

            $itemName = $response["item_name"];
            $amount = $response["payment_gross"];
            $myEmail = $response["receiver_email"];
            $userEmailPaypalId = $response["payer_email"];
            $paymentStatus = $response["payment_status"];
            $paypalTxId = $response["txn_id"];
            $currency = $response["mc_currency"];

            // check the payment_status is Completed
            if($paymentStatus!="Completed") {
                payment_complete();
                emailer($userEmailPayPalID);

            } else {
                payment_incomplete($paymentStatus);
            }

            /*
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            checkIfTransactionHasAlreadyBeenProcessed($paypalTxId);
            // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            checkThatPaymentIsReceivedAtYourEmailAddress($myEmail);
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            checkPaymentAmountAndCurrency($amount, $currency);
            // process the order
            processOrder();
            } else {
            exitCode();
            */
        }
    }
        fclose ($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice you're connecting to `www.sandbox.paypal.com`. I believe you want to connect to `api.sandbox.paypal.com`.

Comment: Thanks for that @tomwhipple. I scrapped that version of my code and used  a cURL version, which worked great. It uses a different url altogether. I recommend others do the same. Otherwise it's a minefield of potential issues.